# Existing 3rd party software migration

Tags: macos, mac, cpu, 3rd-party

Did Apple mention/provide a way to upgrade existing 3rd party software once systems with the new CPU are released or are we expected to buy from scratch? Does anyone remember how they handled this during transition to Intel?

Comment: Rosetta and apps in the Mac app store probably just need a recompile. The basic os and libraries have run i6 different cpus before arm. I have used 5

Comment: and if you use a piece of software that is non-functional on ARM **and** Rosetta2 you will have to purchase an upgrade (if available) or alternative software. The option you are offered is just that *an option.* You don't have to upgrade, you can stick with your current hardware and software. Many people do that now. Heck I have an old (PPC) PowerMac running MacOS9 and MacOS Tiger, that I use from time to time to access old applications and data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the end user, Apple will be doing it the same way as they did for the transition to Intel.

New apps will be released with effectively, 'two apps in one' - originally known as a fat binary or Universal app - which can run on either platform. Legacy apps will run under an invisible translator, originally known as Rosetta & now, unsurprisingly as Rosetta 2. Universal will be, by the same token, Universal 2.

There's Apple's main press notification at [Apple announces Mac transition to Apple silicon](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2020/06/apple-announces-mac-transition-to-apple-silicon/) but [The Verge](https://www.theverge.com/21304182/apple-arm-mac-rosetta-2-emulation-app-converter-explainer) has a more consumer-friendly explanation

> That’s where Rosetta 2 comes in: It’s an emulator built into macOS Big
> Sur that will enable ARM Macs to run old Intel apps. Rosetta 2
> essentially “translates” instructions that were written for Intel
> processors into commands that Apple’s chips can understand. Developers
> won’t need to make any changes to their old apps; they’ll just work.
> (The original Rosetta was released in 2006 to facilitate Apple’s
> transition from PowerPC to Intel. Apple has also stated that it will
> support x86 Macs “for years to come,” as far as OS updates are
> concerned. The company shifted from PowerPC to Intel chips in 2006,
> but ditched support for the former in 2009; OS X Snow Leopard was
> Intel-only.)
>
> Rosetta 2 will allow apps built for Intel chips
> to run on Apple’s new processors without any work from the developer
> You don’t, as a user, interact
> with Rosetta; it does its work behind-the-scenes. “Rosetta 2 is mostly
> there to minimize the impact on end-users and their experience when
> they buy a new Mac with Apple Silicon,” says Angela Yu, founder of the
> software-development school App Brewery. “If Rosetta 2 does its job,
> your average user should not notice its existence.”

Comment: Snow Leopard had Rosetta as an optional download. It was removed from the OS completely in Lion.

Answer (score 3):

Two notable differences between 'old' Rosetta and 'new' Rosetta are:

1. Rosetta 2 will 'pre-compile' its translation before the app is launched. The old Rosetta would 'translate' PPC code to Intel anew each time the app was executed.
2. PPC CPUs were 'Big-endian' (the order in which multi-byte words were stored), whereas Intel and ARM chips are both 'little-endian'. That removes one of the major headaches and causes of problems in translation.